# Tools For Regression Testing

Tags: automated-testing, tools, learning, regression-testing

As part of our final year project we are planning to work on a efficient technique to improve the Regression testing phase.In most of the papers i've read they've used a Tool "DejaVu" to find out the modification traversing test cases and few papers have also used a tool TestTube.I've been searching over the net for these tools but couldn't find them.Can some one give me pointers as to where i can find these tools?

Comment: Are you looking purely test automation tools, or also other efficient ways to find what is modifications and what to test ( manually? ). I ask this because on some cases efficiently focused manual testing is the msot efficient way for regression testing.

Comment: What kind of project do you maintain? What is a project technology stack?

Comment: This question should be closed because: Just Google It.  "Recommend a..." questions are generally prohibited on other SE sites.

Comment: I have to agree with Sammy, this doesn't really have a specific problem to solve. It's just a dump of various tools.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some tools for you ;

Selenium - http://docs.seleniumhq.org/

Watir - http://watir.com/

DejaVu - https://www.npmjs.org/package/dejavu

Answer (score 1):

And here are a couple of others:

- [Cucumber](http://cukes.info/)
- [Robot Framework](http://robotframework.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Here're couple of other tools:

TestingWhiz - http://www.testing-whiz.com/

TestComplete - http://smartbear.com/